# how to extract stats component with solrj 4.9.0

Tags: java, statistics, solrj, solr-query-syntax

I have a solr query like this

```
q=categories:cat1 OR categories:cat2&stats=true&stats.field=count&stats.facet=block_num
```

Basically, I want to get the sum(count) group by block num.

This query works on a browser.  But with solrj, I could not access the stats fields from Response obj.  I can do a response.getFieldStatsInfo().  But it is not what I want.  Here is how I construct the query

```
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(q);       
    query.add("stats", "true");
    query.add("stats.field", "count");
    query.add("stats.facet", "block_num");
```

With a debugger, I could see that the response has a private statsInfo object and it has the information I am looking for.  But there is no api to access the object.

I would like to know if there is

1. a better way to query a solr server other than solrj (curl? how do you parse the response?
2. a better way to construct my query.  maybe using group instead of stats?
3. a way to access the hidden statsInfo object in the query response()?  [it is so frustrated.  I can see all the info I need in the private obj on my debugger!]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do something like this:

```
// Field names
private static final String FIELD_ONE = "field_one";
private static final String FIELD_TWO = "field_two";

// Initialized somewhere in constructor
private final HttpSolrServer solrClient;

public void printStats() throws SolrServerException {
    final SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*:*");
    query.setGetFieldStatistics(true);
    query.setGetFieldStatistics(FIELD_ONE);
    query.setGetFieldStatistics(FIELD_TWO);
    final QueryResponse response = solrClient.query(query);

    final FieldStatsInfo fieldOneStats = response.getFieldStatsInfo().get(FIELD_ONE); 
    System.out.println(fieldOneStats.getSum());
    System.out.println(fieldOneStats.getMin());
    System.out.println(fieldOneStats.getMax());

    final FieldStatsInfo fieldTwoStats = response.getFieldStatsInfo().get(FIELD_TWO);
    System.out.println(fieldTwoStats.getSum());
    System.out.println(fieldTwoStats.getMin());
    System.out.println(fieldTwoStats.getMax());
}
```